# Explain static class attribute binding notation

Tags: ember.js

I have come across the following code:

```
<i {{bindAttr class=":feed-expand-icon :icon-plus isActivitiesVisible:icon-minus"}}></i>
```

I mean specifically the :feed-expand-icon and :icon-plus.  I assume the icon-minus class is added if isActivitiesVisible is true.

Could somebody explain how the class attribute is being bound in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `feed-expand-icon` and `icon-plus` classes will be added anyway.

It's a convenient way to  mix "static" classes and dynamically computed ones (like `icon-minus` in your case).